# Formula for $E(|X-Y|)$ for i.i.d. random variables $X$ and $Y$, in terms of their CDF

Tags: probability, expectation

> Assuming that $X$ and $Y$ are i.i.d. random variables with CDF $F$, prove that $$\mathbb{E}|X-Y| = 2\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}F(t)(1-F(t))\,\textrm{d}t.$$

So I begin: $\mathbb{E}|X-Y| = \mathbb{E}(X-Y)\mathbb{1}_{\{X{\geq}Y\}} + \mathbb{E}(Y-X)\mathbb{1}_{\{X{\leq}Y\}}$.
Since $X,Y$ are identically distributed, those two expected values are equal, I think.
So I need to show that $$\mathbb{E}(X-Y)\mathbb{1}_{\{X{\geq}Y\}} = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}F(t)(1-F(t))\,\textrm{d}t.$$

I try: 
$$\mathbb{E}(X-Y)\mathbb{1}_{\{X{\geq}Y\}} = \int_{\{X-Y{\geq}0\}}(X-Y)F(\textrm dx)F(\textrm dy) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{x}(x-y)F(\textrm dy)F(\textrm dx).$$

Is this any good? Do I have to find CDF of $X-Y$ now? If so, how do I find it? Is there a better way?

Comment: Expand RHS to $\int_{\mathbb R} P(X \le t)P(Y > t) \,\textrm dt + \int_{\mathbb R} P(X \le t)P(Y > t) \,\textrm dt$. The variables $X, Y$ are independent, so the expression under integral is equal to $P(X \le t, Y > t)$. Now recall that we can use the Fubini theorem here.

Comment: "Do I have to find CDF of X−Y now?" By all means, no... Hint to complete your good start: Prove then integrate with respect to $P$ the almost sure identity $$(X-Y)\mathbf 1_{\{X\geqslant Y\}}=\int_\mathbb R\mathbf 1_{\{Y\leqslant t\}}\,\mathbf 1_{\{X\geqslant t\}}\mathrm dt.$$

Answer (score 0):

This is a beautiful and useful theorem - thank you for your question.
As a general rule it is often easier to shrink the larger side than to expand the compact statement:

$\int^{\infty}_{-\infty} F(t)(1-F(t))dt=\int^{\infty}_{-\infty} P(X>t)P(Y \leq t))dt=\int^{\infty}_{-\infty} E[1_{X>t}]E[1_{Y \leq t}]dt=\int^{\infty}_{-\infty} E[1_{X>t}1_{Y \leq t}]dt=\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}E[1_{X>Y}1_{X>t}1_{Y \leq t}]dt=E[\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}1_{X>Y}1_{X>t}1_{Y \leq t}dt]=E[\int^{X}_{Y}1_{X>Y}1_{X>t}1_{Y \leq t}dt]=E[1_{X>Y}\int^{X}_{Y}1_{X>t}1_{Y \leq t}dt]=E[1_{X>Y}\int^{X}_{Y}1dt]=E[(X-Y)1_{X>Y}]$

Remind yourself that for the expected value the event $\{X=Y\}$ has no effect. You should be good now.
For these questions always use $P(A)=E[1_A]$ and then apply Fubini's theorem, as I did.